# HTML input number moves cursor off center when typing letters

Tags: html, css

With an `<input type="number">` field that is styled with `text-align: center`, it works perfectly with numerical input but will move the cursor to the left of the input field if given an alphanumeric character (although it is not displayed).

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jbe55o0g/

How can this be prevented such that the cursor remains in the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `<input type="number">` for numbers only, then you can allow only numeric input using javascript. now the cursor remains in the center :

```css
input[type=number]{
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to also mention that MDN says charCode is deprecated and recommends KeyboardEvent.key instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, or willing to use, and don't want to be writting that line on all number inputs, you can use the following code:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress',"input[type='number']", function(event){
    return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;
})
```

It will make the same effect as adding the onkeypress attribute, fixing the center issue you were having.